# Should old/legacy/unused code be deleted from source control repository?

Tags: version-control

I've encountered this in multiple projects. As the code base evolves, some libraries, applications, and components get abandoned and/or deprecated.

1. Most people prefer to keep them in. The usual argument is that the code does not really take any space, it can be left alone until needed again.
   So a repository slowly turns into a cesspool of legacy code, where it's hard to find anything.
   Another argument for keeping old code around is that new people will not be tempted to try to implement something that was implemented in the past, but didn't quite work out.
2. Some people delete old code, since it creates clutter, raises more questions for new people, and you can restore any old snapshot of the code base anyway.
   However you can't always find the old code if you don't know where to look, as none of the (common) VCS I know offer search over the entire repository including all historical revisions, and the only way to search the old files is to check out the revision where the deleted file exists.

What would be a good approach to repository management?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Cacovsky it didn't exist back then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Remove it. It's clutter - if it doesn't serve a point or is confusing, it's better gone.
2. `git grep` or similar.

Answer (score 10):

**Unused code does take up space in peoples' minds**. Unused and unnecessary code clutters peoples' mental models and makes it harder to understand what everything in the repository is there for (*"oh, don't worry about that, we don't use it anymore"*). It is good to delete code from the repository in these circumstances, but it may be helpful to document (on a wiki or similar) what old applications/components/etc have been deleted, why they were deleted, and where they can be found.

Answer (score 3):

We have a branch that we copy stale libraries and projects to before deleting them from trunk.

```
repo
  +- trunk
  +- tags
  |   +- old-code
  |       +- project1
  |       +- project2
  |          ...
  +- branches
```

Though, to be honest, I can't really think of a time when we've actually gone back to an old project and resurrected it...

Answer (score 2):

Branch the original code. Clean up the master/trunk and future releases.

The legacy code is there for whomever  may or may not need it.

As far as searching for the file, I know git can do this. But in general you just search the commit logs of any repository

```
git log --all -- legacyfile
```

Then find the file in the branch:

```
git branch --contains $filehash
```

*edit* Just wanted to add that on several occasions I've had a need to go back and find files in other projects that were considerably old, 5 or 10 years or so. I was very grateful that it was still there.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal Subversion repository, which is full of abandoned projects, I move things I don't want to see any more under an /attic directory.  I could just as well delete them but, at the cost of one extra directory at the multi-project root, I don't have to go searching around history when I want to find something I thought I don't need any more.

Comment: I do this too. I call it `_archive`. Every now and then I dig through it to pull out old stuff I tried that didn't fly, but has some research value.

Answer (score 2):

Remove it. If it's got no tests, you don't even know if it still works. If there are any parts of it that are useful, pull them out. Old code always holds you back. If you can't easily rebuild functionality you had in the old code, either you shouldn't have replaced it, or your new code is no good.

For projects bringing on new members: The more code you have, the longer it takes them to learn the ropes, and the more difficult it is to make changes. Cruft is only going to cause confusion. Old code is only going to have meaning to those that were around when it worked.

For my personal projects, I have a habit of moving failed ideas into an `_archive` folder. That folder is only of use for reference, and later attempts. Were the projects for mass consumption they would be removed immediately to minimize the code base size.